# Ошибки модуля jsdom при запуске файла на nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.При запуске js файла в консоли возникают следующие ошибки (jsdom 11.2.0):
[image]
TypeError:require<...>.jsdom is not a function.

Comment: Скриншоты плохо индексируются поисковиками. Пожалуйста, приведите сообщение об ошибке в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 1):

Помещать свой код в `Program Files` - это очень плохая идея. Переложи куда-нибудь ещё.

Затем открой консоль непосредственно для папки, в которой находится код и выполни команду

```
npm i jsdom
```

А потом уже запускай свой код

```
node top.js
```

предварительно исправив в нём

> ```
> window = require('jsdom').jsdom().createWindow();
> ```

на

```
window = require('jsdom').jsdom.createWindow();
```

PS: Если команды `npm` и `node` недоступны, пропиши каталог nodejs в `path`.

Comment: Сделала, ошибка осталась прежней.

Comment: @Blackbonny, дополнил ответ.